# Deciding number of comparisons from equation (quicksort)

Tags: time-complexity, quicksort

[Here is the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkT54.png)

So C(0) and C(1) such = 0 because it is the base case

But why does the equation say that the C(n) (number of comparisons) ≤ C(|S|) + C(|B|) + cost of splitting the list?

I mean sure, the number of comparisons in S + B can never be greater than C(n), but why is to formulated like that when I have to answer on how many comparisons are needed to split the list into two sublists?

Comment: This may be more appropriate for https://cs.stackexchange.com/. That said, note that C(n) is the number of comparisons *to completely sort the list*, and C(|S|) is the number of comparisons *to completely sort the left half* after the partition has already happened.

Comment: So the number of comparisons to get it into two sublists would be 2(N/2 -1) right?

Comment: Or would it be more correct to say that the number of comparisons is 2^i(n/2^i-1)?

Comment: Ya I think you're on the right track. You compare each of the n-1 non-pivot elements to the pivot, so you only need n-1 comparisons to do one partition.